# mutating dna in parallel lists python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
def mutations (list_a,string1,name,list_b):
    """ (list of str, str, list of str, list of str) -> NoneType
    """


    dna=list_a
    for i in range(len(list_b)):
        strand=dna[:dna.index(list_b[i])]
        string1=string1[string1.index(list_b[i]):]
        dna[strand+string1]
```

---

```
>>>dna=['TGCAGAATTCGGTT','ACGTCCCGGGTTGC']
>>>mutations(dna,'CCCGGGGAATTCTCGC',['EcoRI','SmaI'],['GAATTC','CCCGGG'])
>>>mutated
>>>['TGCAGAATTCTCGC','ACGTCCCGGGGAATTCTCGC']
```

It's suppose to modify the first parameter. So basically im trying to modify list_a and making it change to `['TGCAGAATTCTCGC','ACGTCCCGGGGAATTCTCGC']` however, i get an error saying

```
strand=dna[:dna.index(string1[i])]. 

ValueError: 'GAATTC' is not in list
```

Also, is there a way if the sequence does not exist, it doesn't modify the function?

Comment: mutated is a list of str, clean is the str, seq is the recognition sequence(dna strands)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE].

Comment: @jojo sorry about that i updated the code

Comment: @cricket_007 so basically im just modifying the first parameter and im not returning anything

Comment: the problem is that your `dna` is a list which indeed does not contain `GAATTC`. It's first element does. Does this help?

Comment: We are not all biologists. You need to explain what a 1-cutter is.

Comment: yea it does kinda but i dont get it, the first item in the list is 'TGCAGAATTCGGTT' and it contains 'GAATTC'

Comment: yes, but you write `dna.index(recognition[i])` which, in the first iteration asks for the index of `GAATTC` in `dna`. **But this is not in `dna`, it is in dna[0]**

Comment: @jojo what can i do?

Comment: @CAVS well for a start you should bring your code to neutral ground, i.e. remove all the specific naming, use neutral names like `list_a`, `list_b` and explain what you want to achieve in a logical statement that is independent on your field. Then people will be able and willing to help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if I understand you correctly, you want to check each element in `list_a` if it contains its corresponding element from `list_b`. If so, you want to modify the element from `list_a` by replacing the rest of the string (including the `list_b` element) with part of a control string that does also contain the element from `list_b`, right?!

Ideally you would put this in your question!!

A way of doing this would be as follow:

```
def mut(list_a, control, list_b):
    check_others = Falsee
    for i in range(len(list_a)):  # run through list_a (use xrange in python 2.x)
        if i == len(list_b):  # if we are at the end of list_b we run will
            # check all other elements if list_b (see below)
            check_others = True
        if not check_others:  # this is the normal 1 to 1 match.
            if list_b[i] in list_a[i]:  # if the element from list_b is in it
                # correct the element
                list_a[i] = list_a[i][:list_a[i].index(list_b[i])] +\
                    control[control.index(list_b[i]):] 
        else:  # this happens if we are at the end of list_b
            for j in xrange(len(list_b)):  # run through list_b for the start
                if list_b[j] in list_a[i]:
                    list_a[i] = list_a[i][:list_a[i].index(list_b[j])] +\
                        control[control.index(list_b[j]):] 
                    break  # only the first match with an element in list_b is used!
```

Comment: im not suppose to be returning anything, im just modifying it

Comment: Python3 `range` is Python2 `xrange` @CAVS

Comment: im using 3.5.2 version

Comment: ah, in this case replace it with `range`. `xrange` is the iterator in python 2.x. in 3.x they've decided to make `range` the iterator already.

Comment: @jojo  i have a problem, if list_a has three strings and list_b has only one string, the function only modifies the first string in list_a

Comment: @CAVS the way I understood you was that you want a element wise comparison, i.e. check if element 1 of `list_b` is in element 1 of `list_a`, check if element 2 of `list_b` is in element 2 of `list_a` and so on. Is that not what you want?

Comment: yes but the thing is list_b can have same number of strings as list_a or have different number of strings

Comment: @jojo any idea?

Comment: @CAVS but if `list_b` has only 1 element, what do you want element 2 of `list_a` compared to?

Comment: @jojo i want to see if that 1 element from list_b is in any of the elements in list_a. For example, if element 1 is in 2 of the elements from list_a, it would only modify those  elements containing  that element and leave the other element as it is

Comment: @CAVS ah, that looks slightly different then. But what if you have 2 elements in `list_b` and both of them are in the first element of `list_a`, what should happen then? I'll update my answer as soon as this is clear.

Comment: if element 1 from list_b matches element 1 from list_a it modifies, if element 2 from list_b matches element 2 from list_a it modifies and if any of the two elements from list_b match the third element in list_a it would also modify

Comment: @CAVS but what about if element 2 from `list_b` matches element 1 from `list_a` should it then be modified as well?

Comment: @jojo yes it would modify

Answer (score 0):

As described in the comments, `dna` is a list, not a string, so finding a substring won't quite work how you want.

`dna=list_a` is unnecessary, and `dna[strand+string1]` doesn't modify a list, so not sure what you were trying to accomplish there.

All in all, I know the following code doesn't get the output you are expecting (or maybe it does), but hopefully it sets you on the more correct path.

(I removed `name` because it was not used)

```
def mutations (mutated,clean,recognition):
    """ (list of str, str, list of str) -> NoneType
    """

    # Loop over 'mutated' list. We need the index to update the list
    for i,strand in enumerate(mutated):

        # Loop over 'recognition' list
        for rec in recognition:

            # Find the indices in the two strings
            strand_idx = strand.find(rec)
            clean_idx = clean.find(rec)

            # Check that 'rec' existed in both strings
            if strand_idx > 0 and clean_idx > 0:
                # both are found, so get the substrings
                strand_str = strand[:strand_idx]
                clean_str = clean[clean_idx:]

                # debug these values
                print(rec, (strand_idx, strand_str,), (clean_idx, clean_str, ))

                # updated 'mutated' like this
                mutated[i] = strand_str+clean_str
```

And, the output. (The first dna element changed, the second did not)

```
dna=['TGCAGAATTCGGTT','ACGTCCCGGGTTGC']
mutations(dna,'CCCGGGGAATTCTCGC',['GAATTC','CCCGGG'])

print(dna)  # ['TGCAGAATTCTCGC', 'ACGTCCCGGGTTGC']
```

Comment: cricket_007 is there anything else i can do rather than using enumerate

Comment: You *need* the index of the current value in order to update the list. I'm not sure what you are thinking would be the alternative